# Laravel localization file use reactJS

Tags: laravel, reactjs, laravel-5

I am developing a laravel application for different language. I store different localization files and easily use them in blade. But in some part of my application I am using ReactJS, the problem is how to use localization file in reactJS.

Comment: get the language file with ajax?